# mercurial push certain revision

Tags: mercurial

I have searched here, but haven't found any question related to this. I got a problem like this in mercurial:
I manage open source project in bitbucket, so i have clone of the source code in my local. But I also using that project for my own live site, so I made 2 clone of bitbucket repo

```
Bitbucket Repo
|
==local_clone1
|
==local_clone2-> commit1            => commit2    => commit3
                (personalization)     (bug fix)     (add feature)
```

The question is, I want to push commit2 and commit3 back to local_clone1, so later on I can push to Bitbucket repo. But don't want to push commit1, since it has my personal data.

Wondering how we do that in mercurial?

Comment: I'm also interested in the answer, but you probably would not get in stuck if you were using feature branches (named branch per feature/bug fix)

Comment: You're going to get a lot of answers below about how to work around this, but going forward you're better off avoiding it, and you do that by controlling the parentage of your changesets.  If commit2 and commit2, which don't rely on commit1, had as their parent the parent of commit1, then you could easily push using `push -r commit3` and commit1 wouldn't go.  The key is to ask yourself "what is the earliest changeset that could be this commit's parent" and update to that before creating the changeset.  Branches, etc. are just abstractions to make remembering to do that a little easier.

Comment: @zerkms  : For this problem, I can't use branch, since if we want to push commit2 and commit3, we need to merge the branch, in which commit1 will also get merged and pushed to bitbucket

Comment: @Ry4an : still don't really understand your solution. But if we do push commit -r3, then all the ancestors which are commit1, commit2, commit3, will be pushed all together. Whereas we don't want commit1 be pushed

Comment: if the commit before `commit1` is `commit0`, then Ry4an is saying, update to `commit0` before doing `commit1` and *again* before doing `commit2` (because `commit2` doesn't depend on `commit1`). Then you effectively have 2 branches: `commit0 -> commit1` and `commit0 -> commit2`. You can push `commit2` without pushing `commit1`, and in your local clone, can merge `commit1` and `commit2` to get all your changes combined. The same applies to `commit3` if it doesn't depend on `commit2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done without too much difficulty in this case. See [Removing history](http://mercurial.selenic.com/guide/#removing_history) in the Mercurial guide for more information.

Here's the basics of what you'll need to do:

- Go to local_clone2
- Get the revision number (`hg tip` will show you) from the current number. We'll call it 731.
- `hg export 730-731 > ../local_clone1/changes.diff` (or wherever you like)
- Go to local_clone1
- `hg import changes.diff`

You may need to edit things manually; refer to that guide for more info in that case.

Comment: Note that this will of course make new changesets with the same content, but different hash id's, which means a simple pull later and you now have merge conflicts.

Comment: True; for that reason you'd be best advised to throw away local_clone2 and clone afresh (or `rollback` the three revisions).

Comment: Wow, thanks alot. This solution works for me. Since i manage that open source only to allow people to clone, not to commit. SO, no need to worry pull problem. This just works.

Comment: What was meant was if you tried to pull to `local_clone2`. No one else will have those extra three revisions, so that's not an issue elsewhere. If you're satisfied this works, you can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of options:

#### backout

Given a history constructed as:

```
hg init db
cd db
echo >file1
hg ci -Am clone              # rev 0
echo >file2
hg ci -Am personalization    # rev 1
echo >file3
hg ci -Am bugfix             # rev 2
echo >file4
hg ci -Am feature            # rev 3 <tip>
```

Then if the current working directory is the tip, the following commands will "undo" the personalization revision:

```
hg backout 1
hg ci -m backout
```

The advantage is history remains immutable, but shows the addition and backout of the personalization changeset.

#### Mercurial Queues

With the mq extension, history can be edited to remove a changeset:

```
hg qimport -r 1:3  # convert changesets 1-3 to patches
hg qpop -a         # remove all patches (can't delete an applied patch)
hg qdel 1.diff     # delete rev 1's patch
hg qpush -a        # reapply remaining patches
hg qfin -a         # convert all applied patches back to changesets.
```

The advantage is the personalization changeset disappears.  The disadvantage is the changeset hashes change due to the history edit, so this should never be done to changesets that have already been pushed to others.  There is also the risk of a mistake editing history.

Comment: This is probably the correct way to go, but yeah, if you have already shared your changes, you're in for some more work down the line.

Comment: Hm, this solution at the moment, doesn't really fit the need, if we manage open source project. Since the histories still there, so every one that clone our project will see all the histories which contain our personal data.

Comment: Did you read the 2nd option?  The history is removed with that one.